# Tags are need to be separated by comma for Featured meta post in Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, android-app, android-app-feed

In the Stack Exchange Android app **Feed** section, the **Featured meta post** tags are not separated by comma. The **hot, unanswered** section post's tags are separated by comma.

Adding the comma will increases the readability. Screen shot for the reference.

**Note:** I'm not sure this is [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), so I'm tag as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), feel free to re-tag.

[image: FMP 1] [image: FMP 2]

Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in version 1.0.84.

Comment: Yeah. It is fixed in `1.0.84`